# PHP GD problem--not enough permission to make image?

Tags: php, permissions

Error:

```
Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open 'images/xxx/xxx.jpg' for writing: Permission denied in /usr/www/users/xxx/resources/func.createthumbs.php on line 48
images/xxx/xxx/xxx.jpg
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /usr/www/users/xxx/resources/updatethumbs.php:17) in /usr/www/users/xxx/resources/func.createthumbs.php on line 3
```

So... How can I change the permission?  This is being run on a shared server--is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Check images' `chmod` and set it to `644` - via `FTP` client or `shell`.
How change permissions ? Depends of your FTP client.

Comment: Werid - for reading a file it should be enough. Than try change chmod to 666/777 and tell me about results.

Comment: I just took the same exact script and ran it on my windows computer and it worked =P.  I tried 777 and still no luck

Answer (score 1):

use your ftp client to set 0777 (or writing for everyone) for the directory `images/xxx/xxx/`

and it is not GD problem